# infinite loop in cs50 speller assignment

Tags: c, linked-list, infinite-loop, cs50, singly-linked-list

I was working on the cs50 speller assignment, and once I finished debugging the `load` function, the program just ran in an infinite loop without doing or printing anything.

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality

#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// TODO: Choose number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 26 * LENGTH;

// Hash table
node *table[N];

unsigned int word_count;

// Returns true if word is in dictionary, else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    node *tmp = table[hash(word)];
    while (tmp != NULL)
    {
        if (strcasecmp(tmp->word, word) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
int hash(const char *word)
{
    // TODO: Improve this hash function
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(word[i]))
        {
            total += (int)(tolower(word[i]) - 'a');
        }
    }
    return total;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    FILE *dict = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (dict == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    char *word = malloc(LENGTH + 1);
    if (word == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    while (fscanf(dict, "%s", word) == 1)
    {
        node *new = malloc(sizeof *new);
        if (new == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }
        strcpy(new->word, word);
        if (table[hash(word)] == NULL)
        {
            table[hash(word)] = new;
        }
        else
        {
            new->next = table[hash(word)];
            table[hash(word)]->next = new;
        }
        word_count++;
    }
    free(word);
    free(dict);
    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded, else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    if (word_count)
    {
        return word_count;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool unload(void)
{
    node *tmp;
    node *cursor;
    for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH * 25; i++)
    {
        tmp = table[i]->next;
        cursor = table[i]->next;
        while (tmp != NULL)
        {
            tmp = tmp->next;
            free(cursor);
            cursor = tmp;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I have had many errors with this problem, and once I fixed up load there was an infinite loop error in another function. I'm not sure how to pinpoint it- can anyone help?

The infinite loop prints out "MISPELLED WORDS" and then a few lines down it has the white cursor that appears in the console. I know that the program is still running because no `$` sign appears. The program is not waiting for any sort of input because this project does not include any reason to use a cs50 `get_xxx` function or `scanf`.

These are only the helper functions (the assignment is only to implement them) and the rest is written for me, in a separate file:

```
// Implements a spell-checker

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

// Undefine any definitions
#undef calculate
#undef getrusage

// Default dictionary
#define DICTIONARY "dictionaries/large"

// Prototype
double calculate(const struct rusage *b, const struct rusage *a);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Check for correct number of args
    if (argc != 2 && argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./speller [DICTIONARY] text\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // Structures for timing data
    struct rusage before, after;

    // Benchmarks
    double time_load = 0.0, time_check = 0.0, time_size = 0.0, time_unload = 0.0;

    // Determine dictionary to use
    char *dictionary = (argc == 3) ? argv[1] : DICTIONARY;
    // Load dictionary
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
    bool loaded = load(dictionary);
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

    // Exit if dictionary not loaded
    if (!loaded)
    {
        printf("Could not load %s.\n", dictionary);
        return 1;
    }

    // Calculate time to load dictionary
    time_load = calculate(&before, &after);

    // Try to open text
    char *text = (argc == 3) ? argv[2] : argv[1];
    FILE *file = fopen(text, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open %s.\n", text);
        unload();
        return 1;
    }

    // Prepare to report misspellings
    printf("\nMISSPELLED WORDS\n\n");

    // Prepare to spell-check
    int index = 0, misspellings = 0, words = 0;
    char word[LENGTH + 1];

    // Spell-check each word in text
    char c;
    while (fread(&c, sizeof(char), 1, file))
    {
        // Allow only alphabetical characters and apostrophes
        if (isalpha(c) || (c == '\'' && index > 0))
        {
            // Append character to word
            word[index] = c;
            index++;

            // Ignore alphabetical strings too long to be words
            if (index > LENGTH)
            {
                // Consume remainder of alphabetical string
                while (fread(&c, sizeof(char), 1, file) && isalpha(c));

                // Prepare for new word
                index = 0;
            }
        }

        // Ignore words with numbers (like MS Word can)
        else if (isdigit(c))
        {
            // Consume remainder of alphanumeric string
            while (fread(&c, sizeof(char), 1, file) && isalnum(c));

            // Prepare for new word
            index = 0;
        }

        // We must have found a whole word
        else if (index > 0)
        {
            // Terminate current word
            word[index] = '\0';

            // Update counter
            words++;

            // Check word's spelling
            getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
            bool misspelled = !check(word);
            getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

            // Update benchmark
            time_check += calculate(&before, &after);

            // Print word if misspelled
            if (misspelled)
            {
                printf("%s\n", word);
                misspellings++;
            }

            // Prepare for next word
            index = 0;
        }
    }

    // Check whether there was an error
    if (ferror(file))
    {
        fclose(file);
        printf("Error reading %s.\n", text);
        unload();
        return 1;
    }

    // Close text
    fclose(file);

    // Determine dictionary's size
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
    unsigned int n = size();
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

    // Calculate time to determine dictionary's size
    time_size = calculate(&before, &after);

    // Unload dictionary
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
    bool unloaded = unload();
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

    // Abort if dictionary not unloaded
    if (!unloaded)
    {
        printf("Could not unload %s.\n", dictionary);
        return 1;
    }

    // Calculate time to unload dictionary
    time_unload = calculate(&before, &after);

    // Report benchmarks
    printf("\nWORDS MISSPELLED:     %d\n", misspellings);
    printf("WORDS IN DICTIONARY:  %d\n", n);
    printf("WORDS IN TEXT:        %d\n", words);
    printf("TIME IN load:         %.2f\n", time_load);
    printf("TIME IN check:        %.2f\n", time_check);
    printf("TIME IN size:         %.2f\n", time_size);
    printf("TIME IN unload:       %.2f\n", time_unload);
    printf("TIME IN TOTAL:        %.2f\n\n",
           time_load + time_check + time_size + time_unload);

    // Success
    return 0;
}

// Returns number of seconds between b and a
double calculate(const struct rusage *b, const struct rusage *a)
{
    if (b == NULL || a == NULL)
    {
        return 0.0;
    }
    else
    {
        return ((((a->ru_utime.tv_sec * 1000000 + a->ru_utime.tv_usec) -
                  (b->ru_utime.tv_sec * 1000000 + b->ru_utime.tv_usec)) +
                 ((a->ru_stime.tv_sec * 1000000 + a->ru_stime.tv_usec) -
                  (b->ru_stime.tv_sec * 1000000 + b->ru_stime.tv_usec)))
                / 1000000.0);
    }
}
```

I didn't write this other file, and I don't completely understand it (I'm not supposed to) but it's where the functions are actually called.

edit: thank you so much to Chqrlie for helping me out! Here is my updated code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>

#include "dictionary.h"



// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// Hash table
node *table[N];

unsigned int word_count;

// Returns true if word is in dictionary, else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    node *tmp = table[hash(word)];
    while (tmp != NULL)
    {
        if (strcasecmp(tmp -> word, word) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        tmp = tmp -> next;
    }
    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
int hash(const char *word)
{
    // TODO: Improve this hash function
    int total = 0;
    unsigned char c;
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(word); i < n; i++)
    {
        c = word[i];
        if (isalpha(c))
        {
            total += (int) (tolower(c) - 'a');
        }
    }
    if (total >= 0 && total <= N - 1)
    {
        return total;
    }
    else
    {
        return N - 1;
    }
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    FILE *dict = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (dict == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    char *word = malloc(LENGTH + 1);
    if (word == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    while (fscanf(dict, "%" STR(LENGTH) "s", word) == 1)
    {
        node *new = malloc(sizeof *new);
        if (new == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }
        strcpy(new->word, word);
        if (table[hash(word)] == NULL)
        {
            table[hash(word)] = new;
            new->next = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            new -> next = table[hash(word)];
            table[hash(word)] = new;
        }
        word_count++;
    }
    free(word);
    free(dict);
    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded, else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    return word_count;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool unload(void) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        while (table[i]) {
            node *tmp = table[i];
            table[i] = tmp->next;
            free(tmp);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I am only running into one error, and I genuinely have no idea how it's even possible. My program prints out everything it should (words misspelled, words in dictionary, etc) but at the end, It runs an infinite loop again - no $ sign appears and the white cursor just stays there forever. This is especially confusing because after all of those printf statements are done, the program should immediately return 0. Does anyone have any idea where this could be happening?

(note - the speller file is the same as it was before, and I think it must be where the error is happening.)

Comment: What does an infinite loop error look like? What are the symptoms? What makes you think of an infinite loop? Are you sure that the program is not e.g. waiting for input or something? Where in the shown code exactly is the loop which turns infinite? Please provide a [mre] to demonstrate the problem you observe.

Comment: @Peter Van Voorhis Looking at this function unsigned int size(void)
{
    if (word_count)
    {
        return word_count;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
} it can be concluded that it seems you are paid for the number of typed symbols.:) You can even improve it writing  if (word_count != 0 ) instead of  if (word_count)

Comment: Run your program in a debugger to find out what's going on. If you cannot use a debugger, add output for debugging purposes (a.k.a. `printf` debugging).

Comment: The `unload` function has at least one bug. You need to check if the table entry is not NULL before `table[i] -> next;`.

Comment: There is no way the shown code can output "MISPELLED WORDS" (not to speak of not being buildable/runnable). Please provide a [mre] which demonstrates what you observe. I guess you need to add a `main()` and some data to process provided by it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- with `N` defined as `const unsigned int N = 26 * LENGTH;` you cannot define a global array of length `N`: `node *table[N];` does not conform to the C Standard.  You should either write:

  - `#define N (26 * LENGTH)` or
  - enum { N = 26 * LENGTH };`
- function `hash` should return an `unsigned int` value, and you should make sure the return value is in the range `0` to `N-1`.
- the functions/macros `isalpha` and `tolower` are not defined for all `char` values on platforms where `char` is a signed type. You should either cast the `char` argument as `(unsigned char)` or use an `unsigned char` variable to avoid the undefined behavior:

  ```
  // Hashes word to a number
  unsigned int hash(const char *word)
  {
      // TODO: Improve this hash function
      unsigned int total = 0;
      for (int i = 0; word[i]; i++)
      {
          unsigned char ch = word[i];
          if (isalpha(ch))
          {
              total += tolower(ch) - 'a';
          }
      }
      return total % N;
  }
  ```
- `fscanf(dict, "%s", word)` will cause a buffer overflow if the input file has a word longer than `LENGTH`. You should pass the maximum number of characters to store into the destination array before the null terminator this way:

  ```
  #define STR(x)  xSTR(x)
  #define xSTR(x) #x

  while (fscanf(dict, "%" STR(LENGTH) "s", word) == 1)
  ```
- `table[hash(word)]->next = new;` is causing an infinite loop because `new->next` was set to `table[hash(word)]` just before.  Hence if there is a collision in the hash table, you will have a 2 element circular list at `table[hash(word)]`.  You should instead write `table[hash(word)] = new`. Inserting `new` in the hash table can be done without the test and the hash code should be computed only once:

  ```
      strcpy(new->word, word);
      unsigned int h = hash(word);
      new->next = table[h];
      table[h] = new;
  ```
- the `size` function should be simplified as:

  ```
  unsigned int size(void) {
      return word_count;
  }
  ```
- the `unload` function is bogus too: you should iterate to `i < N` and you should free all elements, starting at `table[i]` instead of `table[i]->next`:

  ```
  // Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful, else false
  bool unload(void) {
      for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
          while (table[i]) {
              node *tmp = table[i];
              table[i] = tmp->next;
              free(tmp);
          }
      }
      return true;
  }
  ```

> *I didn't write this other file, and I don't completely understand it (I'm not supposed to) but it's where the functions are actually called.*

Good for you! The style of the `main` function is not perfect and the loop `char c; while (fread(&c, sizeof(char), 1, file))` instead of the classic `int c; while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF)` is not recommended, especially when `c` is to be passed to the character class functions defined in `<ctype.h>`.  Note also that the last word of the text file will not be checked if the file does not have a newline or another word separator after it.

Answer (score 1):

The function `load` has several bugs.

The first one is that the data member next is not set within this if statement

```
    if (table[hash(word)] == NULL)
    {
        table[hash(word)] = new;

    }
```

and as a result has an indeterminate value. If only one string will be read from the file when using this node will invoke undefined behavior.

In the else part of the if statement

```
    else
    {
        new -> next = table[hash(word)];
        table[hash(word)] -> next = new;
    }
```

The both statements can result in numerous memory leaks due to overwriting the data member `next` of the pointer `table[hash(word)]` with newly added node. And the obtained list will be a circular list that can make a loop infinite.

Pay attention to that the function `size` defined by you like

```
unsigned int size(void)
{
    if (word_count)
    {
        return word_count;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

can look much simpler like

```
unsigned int size(void)
{
    return word_count;
}
```